# how to pass value of hidden column as extra parameter to editurl in jqgrid

Tags: url, jqgrid, edit

i have a hidden column in my grid. i want to pass the value of this column to my editurl when i want to add a new row. I tried using

```
    onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata) {

               var rowid = postdata[this.id + "_id"]; 

               var dataF = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getCell', rowid, 'account');

            return {account:dataF};
            }
```

inside the add options of navgrid but this passes NULL value !

please help

thanks.